# SP Flash Tool Windows 10

Tags: applications, rom-flashing

I am unable to run the flash tool. Says the following dll files are missing although they are shown in the unzipped file. Flashtoollib.dll   FlashtoolllibEx.dll  QtWebKit4.dll  SLA_Challenge.dll  I am running Windows 10  I have tried downloading the flash tool file a few times but get the same messages. Can anyone help please?

Comment: maybe it's a typo but to me it looks like you did not even know the difference between file and folder. are you sure you unzipped files?

Comment: Yes, all unzipped.